# Convert JSON String to Dictionary in Android

Tags: android

I have the following json formatted string that is returned from the web service:

```
{"Success":false,"Message":"This version is not supported"}
```

I am using the following code to invoke the web service:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

client.get("http://mywebsite/check/getcompatibilityinfo", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {
        System.out.println(response);
    }
});
```

The response contains the json string now I need to access the Success and the Message property. Is there any simple way to do it without using complicated third party libraries?

Comment: response.optString("Success") will work here. Doesn't get easier than this. :)

Comment: optString is not defined!!!

Comment: The response you get back must be a JSONObject right? On that call response.optString. If your JSON is the one above, it will work.

Comment: The response I get back is a JSON string as indicated in the code above.

Comment: Right, then @MiStr's answer is right. Just use optString and optBoolean instead of getString and getBoolean.

Comment: Can you see the code above? The response is of *type* string which is JSON formatted. JSONObject is not working either it throws unreported exception org.json.JSONException; must be caught or declared to be thrown when initializing the object.

Comment: JSONObject constructor throws JSONException, add try/catch when creating JSONObject.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The JSONObject class is already available in your Android codebase (no 3rd party dependencies). Since your example uses normal (simple) JSON, you can use:

```
try {
    JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject(response);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

boolean success = responseJSON.getBoolean("Success");
String message = responseJSON.getString("Message");
```

Comment: you might add some defensive codes and check to see that the object exists first:   if (!responseJSON.isNull("Success") { boolean success = responseJSON(getBoolnea("Success")};

Comment: ...as well as checking for the exception when calling constructor for JSONObject :)

Comment: Yeah I wrapped in try/catch blocks and now it is okay. I am surprised that Java will force me to include the try/catch blocks. This is insane!